# Can't open Eclipse after installing Spring STS

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-neon

After installing Spring STS in Eclipse, I can't open Eclipse.

Whenever I try to open Eclipse, it force closes within a minute.

This is what the eclipsec.exe tells:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
 bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry aft
er the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: D:\Akkil\Mynewworksp
ace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration\logback.1.7.0.20160
603-1933.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://464.fwk829985002:1/org/slf4j/impl/Stat
icLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://464.fwk829985002:2/org/slf4j/impl/Stat
icLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorSta
ticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
WARNING: You are binding against the deprecated org.eclipse.fx.javafx - please r
emove all javafx imports
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007fef66cca90, pid=5888
, tid=0x0000000000001714
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_101-b13) (build 1.8.0_101-b1
3)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.101-b13 mixed mode windows-amd6
4 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [MSVCR120.dll+0x8ca90]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client vers
ions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Akkil\Javatools\Eclipse Neon\eclipse\hs_err_pid5888.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

the hs_err_pid5888.log says
[log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZW-Dvxhxnv42UblPIdRcyG4nwCfk07f4nm7isdopP7M/edit?usp=sharing/%22log%22)

I just SET a "HOME" path in windows 7 but it doesn't solve my problem.

I am using Eclipse 4.6 Neon

Comment: It looks to me that the HOME is not the error (it says Warning). Don't you have more logs? Don't you have a dialog displaying the error?

Comment: @Andrés i don't see any other log info,if you can tell me where can i find logs other than this,please tell me

Comment: I suggest you to run the eclipse from command line and copy/paste the output here so we can help you diagnosing the problem

Comment: please exlpain details about running eclipse in command line @Andrés

Comment: You need to open a windows terminal. Look how to do it (usually "Windows > Start menu > Run" and type cmd), then cd (change directory) to your eclipse installation folder, then run eclipse.

Comment: @Andrés i just recorrected the question,i think now you can look up for solving this issue. thanks in advance

Comment: It looks you are running java 64 bits. Please make sure you are running also the 64 bit eclipse version. In case your Windows 7 is 32 bits, then make sure you are both running eclilpse 32 & java 32 bit. Hope it helps

Comment: Otherwise, you should check at `D:\Akkil\Javatools\Eclipse Neon\eclipse\hs_err_pid5888.log`, your log indicates that there are more informations in this file.
And I think Andrès is hitting the right point with the Windows version, as it looks like it is related to memory values.

Comment: @Andrés my jdk,jre and eclipse all are 64bit

Comment: @akkil Please check the OS architecture you have? Help here: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-determine-what-version-windows-7-you-have

Comment: win 7 version 6.1 build 7600 ulitmate edition @Andrés

Comment: @akkil 32 or 64 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just moved my entire workspace and restart the eclipse,it works fine but whenever i click the optional dashboard of spring suite tool causes the error coming back. so uninstalling  the optional Dashboard makes the eclipse better.

Comment: Hmmm... the dashboard uses JavaFX and the there was some message in your error dumps about JavaFX as well. So it is possible the JavaFX bits are acting up. Not unlikely as the JVM is crashing in native code. Its a bit odd the 'hs_err_pid5888.log' is so sparse. Usually has loads of info about where the crash occurred and this often helps pinpoint the native lib that's repsonsible. Is that really the whole of the log?

Comment: @Kris [log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZW-Dvxhxnv42UblPIdRcyG4nwCfk07f4nm7isdopP7M/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks that does look like it crashed in JavaFX native code.

Answer (score 0):

From log it shows, you have crasehd in JavaThread "JavaFX Application Thread", it does look like similar issue of https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8149737, 8u102 has fix for this. upgrade your java to 8u102, and try else report it - http://bugreport.java.com/